# How to get Response history after few redirects in HTTPConnectionPool urllib3

Tags: python, connection-pooling, urllib3

I am using `HTTPConnectionPool` of `urllib3` for post requests. Here in the code `http://something.com/file.php` has `2` redirects. After the request is complete I am getting final response in the `headers` and `data`. How to see the history of redirects that was done by the server on the meantime?

```
headers = {.....}
data = {...}
newPool = urllib3.HTTPConnectionPool("something.com",port=80,maxsize=5,headers=headers,retries =5,timeout=10)
r = newPool.request('POST', '/file.php',fields=data,redirect =True)
print r.ststus
print r.headers
print r.data
```

Please Give me some advice. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not built into `urllib3` yet. I've [open an issue (#576)](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/576) to add this feature.

For now, to get the redirect history, you'll either need to manage your own redirects or you could use [`requests`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/) which uses `urllib3` underneath and [implements this feature](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history).